# Swift Mapbox 3.01 Framework

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

Trying to get Mapbox framework 3.0.1 working on Swift iOS 9.1 - Followed all the steps here : https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/#binary 
When rendering the xcode project, I am getting a weird error when the actual map view is called: Couldn't find resource mapbox.png in bundle.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion here. I just updated the docs, but you want to use one of the static library downloads, with the `libMapbox.a`, not the framework. The framework is used for CocoaPods install and soon, in future, will be a standalone install method.

Comment: That makes sense. will try that. Is the install process the same?

Comment: Great. Added Bridge Header and worked fien for Swift 2.0. I dont even have to add the import Mapbox line.